# JavaScript: Existe uma forma de fazer um do-while testar a condição antes do fim do laço?

Tags: javascript, do-while

Contexto: Estou desenvolvendo um RPG baseado em texto e na hora de fazer a mecânica da batalha estou tendo esse 'problema'.

Ex:

```
    function verificarEstado(pessoa){
     if (pessoa.estado != 'normal') {
      /* aqui terá um switch para cada efeito tipo envenenado, sangrando, etc, esses efeitos podem causar dano, então pode ser que um dos combatentes morra nessa etapa*/
      verificarVida(pessoa.vida);
    }
    
    function verificarVida(pessoa){
      if (pessoa.vida<=0){
        /* aqui vem a condição para parar o laço, pois se um dos combatentes morreu, é o fim da luta */
      }
    }
    
    function realizarAtaque(atacante, alvo){
     /* Não vou entrar em detalhes aqui porque não é relevante, o ponto é que eu não quero que essa etapa seja executada se um dos personagens tiver morrido no 'verificarEstado()  */
    }
    
    function iniciarBatalha(jogador, inimigo){
      let ambosVivos=true;
      let turno=1;
    
       do{
    
        verificarEstado(jogador);
        verificarEstado(inimigo);
       
        realizarAtaque(jogador, inimigo);
        realizarAtaque(inimigo, jogador);
       
       turno++;
       } while (ambosVivos);
      }
iniciarBatalha(jogador,inimigo) /* Chamada para o inicio da batalha    */
```

Comment: Qual problema você está tendo? Não ficou claro

Comment: Não entendi a duvida?

Comment: dentro do Do-while estou executando 4 funções, certo?

Quero saber se existe uma forma de, por exemplo, a primeira dessas funções já trocar a condição de verificação e as outras não ser executada. Nesse contexto, um personagem pode morrer na primeira dessas quatro funções, então não faria sentido ele tentar dar um ataque na função seguinte. Eu poderia colocar um if(ambosVivos) envolvendo as funções realizarAtaque(), mas não parece ser a melhor forma. Eu to querendo algo como o "continue" do laço For.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> JavaScript: Existe uma forma de fazer um do-while testar a condição
> antes do fim do laço?

Respondendo diretamente o título da pergunta

Em qualquer estrutura de repetição em JS, você pode realizar um `break` para parar o loop, ou `continue` para iniciar a próxima iteração e interromper a atual. O `continue` neste caso somente irá para a próxima iteração se a condição do loop permanecer verdadeira.

```js
function loop() {
  let i = 0
  do {
    if(i ==3) {
      i += 2
      alert("Continue irá pular para a próxima iteração")
      continue
    }
    
    if(i == 5) {      
      alert("Parar o loop")
      break
    }
    alert("iteração normal")
    i++
  } while(i < 6)
}

loop()
```

> um personagem pode morrer na primeira dessas quatro funções, então não
> faria sentido ele tentar dar um ataque na função seguinte.

Sendo bem simples na solução de acordo com o que você nos mostrou, as funções que podem parar o loop devem retornar um booleano indicando se o loop deve ou não continuar. Caso não deva continuar, você pode realizar um `break`.